# How to track a Work Item through multiple Sprints and track its progress over different sprints?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, sprint

The work item is created in Sprint A and it is still being reworked in Sprint X and how to track its progress through these sprints? Can the history of the WI (work item) be tracked on who was working on it? I need to track the progress of a WI from the birth sprint to its current sprint where it is being reworked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use our Microsoft DevLabs' extension [Feature timeline and Epic Roadmap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.workitem-feature-timeline-extension)

[image]

**Plan** or **track** work items in progress by **visualizing them on a sprint calendar**. Portfolio level work items are worked for multiple sprints and this tool helps you visualize features or epics across sprints.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use two ways:

1. Clone a work item to new sprint and close for old sprint ([Copy or clone work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/copy-clone-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)). This may work for tasks but not with bugs and requirements.
2. Work items contain all history and you can get it with power bi report. [Connect to the Analytics service with Power BI Data Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thank you. But, I just need to track a work item from the sprint it was created till the current sprint and track its current status and overall progress. Hope I make sense.

Comment: That`s  work for the power bi custom report. You can not do that with standard features.